# import ファイル名 from 'フォルダパス';でインポートする。

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Reactで描かれたコードで下記のように使用されているのを見かけてたのですが export名が `Index` なので `import Index from 'hoge';` が正しいように見えるのですが、これでもIndexコンポーネントを `<hoge />` のように使用できるのでしょうか。
詳しい方、教えて頂けると幸いです。宜しくお願い致します。

hoge/index.tsx

```
const Index: React.FC<Props> = route => {}

export default Index;
```

読み込み先

```
import hoge from 'hoge';
```

Answer (score 1):

この `export default` によって任意の名前を使用できるようになってただけだった。

#### 参考

[export defaultってなんだろう](https://qiita.com/rena_m/items/b9e79dc88e5c5bc5b245)